# Search accurev depot for unused workspaces

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

Is there anyway using accurev CLI that I can search for old unused workspaces? Some way that I can get a list of workspaces that havent been accessed in x amount of days for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to create a script.

The logic will be to run the command 'accurev show -fx wspaces'.

From this output, you will see a "Trans" value.  Example output below.

Trans="196431"

This value is the workspace transaction level based upon the last time the workspace was successfully updated.

You can run the command 'accurev hist -fx -p depotname -t TransNumber'

From ths output, you will see a "time" value.  Example output below.

time="1361564066"

This is the time value per workspace transaction level.

You will convert this into a readable format using the command:

perl -e "print scalar localtime(1361564066);"

Example output.
Fri Feb 22 15:14:26 2013

That all being said, you can compare this time against the current time to determine any old workspaces that have not been in use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I have a further question though.  When I do an accurev show one of the things that comes back is fileModTime.  Can I not just use that?

Comment: The fileModTime is the workspace scan threshold value.  This is what is used to determine modified files in your workspace.  Meaning, you can have a very old file with a modified status even though its in a workspace that is actively in use.  So I would not recommend using that value.